# Google Chrome switch "--allow-running-insecure-content" doesn't work anymore

Tags: google-chrome

I run Google Chrome with switch "--allow-running-insecure-content" for a long time and had no troubles at any sites related to running insecure until recently. It started to block certain JavaScript again regardless of the switch. For example, in Gmail I can't open any emails because of this. Console shows errors "The page at https://mail.google.com/... ran insecure content from http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs...". Is there a way to allow running insecure content in Chrome?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure **all** Chrome processes are **stopped**.

Some extensions run Chrome in background and you need to start a **whole new process** with the command line. Try removing any running Chrome process in the **tray** (there is an Exit entry in the contextual menu of the Chrome logo in the tray).
If needed, kill the chrome processes in Task manager.

Answer (score 1):

For someone looking in latest chrome, follow these steps

1. Go to chrome://settings/content/insecureContent
2. It opens following page, add your domain in "Allow"section.
   [image]